# Convert arrayList to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jsp, arraylist, server-side, web-development-server

I am sending an arrayList from a java file to a .jsp file

In order to receive that array I used the following code

```
var words = 
        [
            <c:forEach begin="0" items="${requestScope.WordList}" var = "word">
                word,
             </c:forEach>
        ];
```

however it is not working .. any Idea of how to do it ?

Comment: I don't see a question mark anywhere !

Comment: *it is not working* is too generalized, please be more specific!

Comment: I don't think it is good practice to build JSON arrays this way. Just use a 3rd party library to do that. This kind of approach can create a lot of problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a Java ArrayList of strings to a JavaScript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1):

Possible fix (Bad fix):

```
var words = 
    [
        <c:forEach items="${requestScope.WordList}" var="word" 
         varStatus="status">
          "${word}"<c:if test="${not status.last}">,</c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    ];
```

**OR**

Convert the Java `ArrayList` to `JSON` String, and use `JSON.parse()` to get Javascript object.

Comment: As the type of `word` probably is `string` you will have to put quotes around `${word}`. I.e. put `"${word}",` in the `c:forEach`. A secound problem would be, that you will have a comma at the end of the array definition.

Comment: no not working
for the last line it gave the error expected ; but found ]

Comment: Comma at the end is fine with most browsers

Comment: Don't forget to escape the word string