# Convert Java List to Javascript Array

Tags: java, javascript, android, arrays, list

I have the following java code in my Android application and wanted a way to convert the Java list to an array that can be used in javascript:

Java:

```
public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
    {
             //add to an array object that can be used in Javascript
             webView.loadUrl("javascript:fetchFriends(arrObj)");        
    }               
 }
```

Javascript:

```
  //this is how I want to be able to use the object in Javascript
    function parseFriends(usersObjectFromJava){
       var users = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < usersObjectFromJava.length; i++) {
            var u = {
                Id: usersObjectFromJava[i].id + "",
                UserName: usersObjectFromJava[i].username,
                FirstName: usersObjectFromJava[i].first_name,
                LastName: usersObjectFromJava[i].last_name,
            };
            users[i] = u;
        }
    }
```

Could some help me with the Java code to create the usersObjectFromJava so that it can be used in javascript?

Comment: I could be wrong because I'm not terribly well-read in JS but I would think that you could create a JSON array in Java and then easily read it in JS? http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: Your question doesn't really have enough information to answer. How are you communicating between Java and Javascript?

Comment: @TimB I've updated my question.  I'm using a webView and calling the javascript code as noted.  The Java/javascript interface has been tested and works.

Comment: @Submersed for ajax yes, if the array is being loaded from the server at the same time as the page he can just generate the relevant code to populate the arrays at that time though.

Comment: @prabhu I don't see any update.

Comment: @TimB Hmm, probably didn't save it.  Updated again, do you see it now?

Comment: Please take a look at the Jackson framework, with this you can easily create what you want

Comment: I see it. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that approach so I can't help you. Personally I'd use jQuery to make an ajax call and have the Java web service return a JSON object.

Comment: @TimB No probs, thanks though.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133264/convert-arraylist-to-javascript-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would assume doing this:

Java:

```
public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject tmp;
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
             tmp = new JSONObject();
             tmp.put("Id",users.get(i).id); //some public getters inside GraphUser?
             tmp.put("Username",users.get(i).username);
             tmp.put("FirstName",users.get(i).first_name);
             tmp.put("LastName",users.get(i).last_name);
             arr.add(tmp);
        }

        webView.loadUrl("javascript:fetchFriends("+arr.toString()+")");         
    } catch(JSONException e){
        //error handling
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function fetchFriends(usersObjectFromJava){
   var users = usersObjectFromJava;
}
```

You will have to change the Java-Code a bit (i.e. using public getters or add more/less information to the `JSONObjects`.
`JSON` is included in Android by default, so no external libraries are necessary.

I hope i understood your problem.

Small thing i came across: you where using `fetchFriends` in Java but its called `parseFriends` in Javascript, I renamed them to `fetchFriends`

Comment: Currently testing this out, will let you know how it goes!

Comment: This worked.  I had to do this in javascript to make it work: var users = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userObjectsFromJava));

Comment: @bbuecherl I am facing similar type of issue with JSON.Can you figure it out please??  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945432/how-to-give-java-arraylist-to-javascript-function-using-json

Answer (score 11):

Use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
to convert java objects to **JSON** string, you can do it by

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
TestObject o1 = new TestObject("value1", 1);
TestObject o2 = new TestObject("value2", 2);
TestObject o3 = new TestObject("value3", 3);

List<TestObject> list = new ArrayList<TestObject>();
list.add(o1);
list.add(o2);
list.add(o3);
```

**gson.toJson(list)** will give you

> [{"prop1":"value1","prop2":2},{"prop1":"value2","prop2":2},{"prop1":"value3","prop2":3}]

Now you can use **JSON.parse()**, to deserialize from JSON to Javascript Object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gson Library.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonArray jsonArray = gson.toJsonTree(your_list, TypeClass.class).getAsJsonArray();
```

http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Jackson.
You'll need to add an " @JsonProperty" annotation to every property of your POJOs you want to pass, then do something like this:

```
    String respStr = "";

            for(Object whatever: MyList)    
        {
                JSONObject dato = new JSONObject();                    
                    dato.put("FirstField", whatever.SomeData());        
                        dato.put("SecondField", whatever.SomeData2());

                    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(dato.toString());        
                    post.setEntity(entity);

                           webView.loadUrl("javascript:fetchFriends("+entity+")");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why no answer mentioned about `jaxb`. I am just thinking `jaxb` would be a good fit for this type of problems...

For a sample style of annotated `jaxb` class, please find this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ResponseAsList {
    private List < Object > list = new ArrayList < Object > ();

    public ResponseAsList() {
        // private default constructor for JAXB
    }
    public List < Object > getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List < Object > list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

You will stuff your data in these lists and you will `marshal` either in `xml` or a `json`. After you get a `json` to the client, you can do a `var myArray = JSON.parse(response);`...

Answer (score 1):

Although I typically advocate using something like GSON or Jackson to do JSON conversions for you, its pretty easy to roll your own if you're in a limited environment (like Android) and don't want to bundle a bunch of dependencies.

```
public class JsonHelper {
  public static String convertToJSON(List<GraphUser> users) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (GraphUser user : users) {
      sb.append(convertToJSON(user));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static String convertToJSON(GraphUser user) {
    return new StringBuilder()
      .append("{")
        .append("\"id\":").append(user.getId()).append(",")
        .append("\"admin\":").append(user.isAdmin() ? "true" : "false").append(",")
        .append("\"name\":\"").append(user.getName()).append("\",")
        .append("\"email\":\"").append(user.getEmail()).append("\"")
      .append("}")
      .toString();
  }
}
```

You could obviously make a `toJSON()` method on `GraphUser` to put the logic if you prefer. Or use an injectable json helper library instead of static methods (I would). Or any number of other abstractions. Many developers prefer to separate representation of model objects into their own object, myself included. Personally, I might model it something like this if I wanted to avoid dependencies:

- `interface Marshaller<F,T>` with methods `T marshall(F obj)` and `F unmarshall(T obj)`
- `interface JsonMarshaller<F> extends Marshaller<String>`
- `class GraphUserMarshaller implements JsonMarshaller<GraphUser>`
- `class GraphUserCollectionMarshaller implements JsonMarshaller<Collection<GraphUser>>` which could do type-checking or use the visitor pattern or something to determine the best way to represent this type of collection of objects.

Along the way, I'm sure you'll find some repeated code to extract to super- or composite- classes, particularly once you start modeling collection marshallers this way. Although this can get to be pretty verbose (and tedious), it works particularly well in resource-constrained environments where you want to limit the number of libraries on which you depend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Gson library (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert the Java List Object to JSON. Ensure that the right fields are set like ID, UserName, FirstName, etc and on the java script side that same code would work.

Answer (score -1):

Its just an example, First add javascript interface. It will be a bridge between javascript and java code.
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "interface");

In javascript you can add like this,

```
     "window.interface.setPageCount(pageCount1);"
```

The interface is a keyword in common between java and javascript. create a class JSInterace and define a method setPageCount(int a). The script will return a value, and you can use that value in your java method